# Biding Vue-router params in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I have the following View :

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <Quiz :quizID="this.$route.params.id"/>
    <p>{{this.$route.params.id}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

The value of `this.$route.params.id` is correctly displayed between the `<p>` tags. But the component above doesn't get this value as a parameter. If I force it by writing `<Quiz :quizID="3"/>`, it works and the component `Quiz`with the corresponding ID is displayed.

But as soon I put a variable, nothing works anymore.

Edit : As suggested, here is the `Quiz` component

```
<div>
    <div class="container flex justify-center mx-auto">
    <div class="flex flex-col">
        <div class="w-full">
            <div class="border-b border-gray-200 shadow">
                <table>
                    <tbody class="bg-white">
                        <tr class="whitespace-nowrap" v-for="player in players" :key="player.quizID">
                            <td class="px-6 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500" v-if="player.quizID === quizID">
                                {{player.quizID}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="px-6 py-4" v-if="player.quizID === quizID">
                                {{player.name}}
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Quiz',
    data(){
    return {
      quizzes: [],
      players: []
    }
  },
    props: [
        'quizID'
    ],
    methods: {
    async fetchQuizzes() {
      const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/quizs`)
      const data = await res.json()
      return data.data
    },
    async fetchPlayers() {
      const res = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/players`)
      const data = await res.json()
      return data.data
    }
   
    },
    async created(){
    this.quizzes = await this.fetchQuizzes();
    this.players = await this.fetchPlayers();
    },
    
}
</script>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You can try using a computed property.

Comment: The way you did bind the route param to the component is correct, maybe the type of the prop on `Quiz` is not correct. Can you post the `Quiz` component?

Comment: @LuisBrito I just posted it

Comment: The `Quiz` component seems to be ok, I can't spot anything wrong with it. Did you inspect the `Quiz` using Vue devtools? What is the value for it when inspecting? Did the route has a `:id` param? Did the route show an `id` when inspecting for it?
Use [Vue devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) to inspect the the route and component to spot issues.

Comment: @LuisBrito I founded the issue, the ```v-if``` statement had to take a double equal ```==``` instead of a triple ```===```

Comment: @jules_f happy that you found the issue. That´s happening because the prop that the component is receiving is a String, and you´re comparing it to an Integer using `===`, where JS checks the value and type whilst using `==` JS tries to convert the String to Integer to compare them. To use tripple `=`, you can do `parseInt(this.$route.params.id, 10)` on the parent component, so the child component will receive an integer instead of a String.